# Get only selected lines from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have example file like:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4 #header
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8 # 5th line
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
.......
```

I want to get header and 5th line. I do this:

```
i=0
for line in open('test.txt'):
    if i == 0 or i == 5:
        print(line)
        i+=1
```

But it gives only header. I dont know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to manually increment a counter, it is better to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 0 or i == 4:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have indented the part where you increment `i`, so it executes only if `i == 0` or if `i == 5`. This means `i` is incremented only on the first loop, and stays like that forever, even when the 5th line is read.

The code should be

```
i=0
for line in open('test.txt'):
    if i == 0 or i == 4:
        print(line)
    i+=1
```

where `i == 4` when the 5th line is read, since counting starts from 0.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, to access lines in a file using line numbers, you can also use linecache:

```
import linecache
print(linecache.getline('test.txt', 1))
print(linecache.getline('test.txt', 5))
```

Comment: Note a potential issue with linecache: It reads the entire file into memory, and may not be the most memory friendly way to accomplish this.

Comment: True, but OP does not indicate if memory is a problem, or files are extremely big. Its still interesting alternative to the more straight forward "manual" looping over lines.

Comment: I like the solution; I mainly comment for future viewers to not do this with 10^9 lines...  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

your code work fine just increment i, out of if block

```
i=0
for line in open('test.txt'):
    if i == 0 or i == 4:
        print(line)
    i +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your index is improperly defined, there are two types of for loops:

1. Fixed repetition
2. Foreach loop

Fixed repetition loops for a specified interval whereas foreach loops iterate through a collection. Secondly, you must parse the file into a list of lines. Try either of the two methods below:

Fixed repetition:

```
test = open('test.txt').readlines() # file as list of strings

for index in range(len(test)): # iterate according to the number of lines
    if index == 0 or index == 4: # if line number is 0 or 4
        print(test[line]) # print the line at the line number
```

Foreach loop

```
test = open('test.txt').readlines() # file as list of strings

for line in test: # for every line in the list of lines
    index = test.index(line) # find the line's line number
    if index == 0 or index == 4: # if the line number is 0 or 4
        print(line) # print the line
```

See the comments to understand the differences. And remember the numbering begins at zero, so the fifth line would have a line number of four.